# Fourier transform and $L^1,$ $L^2$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\phi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{\phi}$ be the Fourier transform of $\phi.$

Does this mean that $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{\phi}(x + 2 \pi m)|^2$ converges in the $L^1$ sense on each compact set to a $2 \pi $ periodic function?

Comment: If it converges at $x$, then it converges at $x+2 \pi$ to the same value. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, although the $L^1$ convergence is what I find slightly harder